# анимация не срабатывает в safari при возврате на странице при нажитии назад в браузере

Tags: javascript, jquery

столкнулся с проблемой что анимация не срабатывает на главной странице если мы возвращаемся с внутриней странице (нажали кнопку назад в браузере), это происходить только в сафари, как можно исправить это?

Comment: на ios только или везде?

Comment: только в safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте вот это:

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
        window.location.reload()
    }
});
```

Comment: pageshow - это название функции где написана анимация?

Comment: нет это в jquery что то , если jquery  подключено ничего менять не надо, просто подключить этот код. Так какая то мутка с кешированием страниц, которая на ios системах работает больше чем надо.

Comment: поставил эту функцию и всё норм работает спс